# Separable ODE - Integral involving Elliptic integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to solve the equation
$$ \dot y(t) = -\sqrt{ y(t)^6 + y(t)^2 + a } $$ with $a \leq y(t)^6+y(t)^2$  for all $t\geq 0$. This is a first order separable ODE. According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%201%2Fsqrt%28%20y%5E6%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%20a%20%29) the integral involves elliptic integrals of the first kind. For $a=0$, the [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%201%2F%28-sqrt%28y%5E6%2By%5E2%29%29) involves hyperbolic trigonometric functions. Can this integral be solved avoiding elliptic integrals?. Else, I don't see any hope for getting an explicit solution for the ODE.

Comment: If you want to make the result looking nicer, write
$$y^6+y^2+a=(y^2-r)(y^2-s)(y^2-t)$$ and look at [Wolfram Alpha][1].


[1]:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2Fsqrt%28+%28y%5E2-r%29%28y%5E2-s%29%28y%5E2-t%29+%29

Comment: Does it matter now that $r,s,t\in\mathbb{C}$ while the original coefficients are real?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if you replace $\,y(t)^2\,$ with
$\,y(t)\,$, then the ODE becomes
$$ \dot y(t) = -\sqrt{ y(t)^3 + y(t) + a }. $$
This has a similar solution depending of the elliptic integral $\,F(\cdot|m).\,$ You asked

> Can this integral be solved avoiding elliptic integrals?

The answer is no. It is not avoidable. You wrote

> Else, I don't see any hope for getting an explicit solution for the ODE.

That depends on what you consider an "explicit"
solution. The Legendre [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)
of the first kind is a well studied special
function and there is no reason to avoid it
if it is available for computations.

However, you are asking for an explicit
solution to an ODE and in general, there is no way to get a "closed form" solution  that you want. This case is no exception .

Comment: The  first problem i see is that after [integrating](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F-sqrt%28x%5E3%2Bx%2Ba%29), I get some function of an elliptic integral for which I can not solve for $x$. So I can not get $x$ as a function of $t$ and $a$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "solve for $x$". The case for $\,a=0\,$ involves an $\text{arctanh}\,$. How is that case very different than for $\,a\ne 0\,$ except itinvolves the elliptic integral function $F(\text{arcsin}())$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant solve for $y$ as a function of $t$. After separating and integrating I get something like $g(y) F(sin(y)|m) = t + c$. I have no idea how to solve for $y$ to get a closed form expression $y(t) = h(t,a)$. Also, I am not sure about the replacement you suggest, y^6+y^2 is always positive, so the square root is always real, in your case it is not, right?